# Javascript nav dropping down over flash, and not intercepting mouse events

Tags: javascript, css, flash, actionscript

the nav drops down over flash elements that listen for mouse events. (ROLL_OVER) 
When the nav is in the down position over the flash, I would like to prevent the flash elements under the nav from receiving rollover.

This is not the same issue as the common, js/css nav dropping behind the flash.
and Im using swfobject 2, & wmode:"transparent".

Answer (score 0):

HTML elements on top of JavaScript is always a bit "shady". One solution might be using ExternalInterface with JavaScript, to tell the Flash element that it should be idle. So whenever the JavaScript navigation opens, execute a method on the Flash object which disables all interaction. When the JavaScript navigation closes, do the reverse.